# Copy macro in ComboBox (Form Control) into another cell

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

The idea of this macro is that once Release option is chosen in row 17, row 18 will be hidden based on image.

It worked until I tried to copy the ComboBox into another cell, in this instance row 23:
[image]

```vb
Sub ComboBox5_Change()
cb = ActiveSheet.Shapes("ComboBox5").TopLeftCell.row

With ActiveSheet.Shapes("ComboBox5")
    Cells(cb, 5) = .ControlFormat.List(.ControlFormat.ListIndex)
    If .ControlFormat.List(.ControlFormat.ListIndex) = "Courier" Then
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(cb + 1, 1), Cells(cb + 1, 1)).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(cb + 1, 1), Cells(cb + 1, 1)).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

I created another ComboBox to test it and copy/pasted it to another cell which led to the same results.

Comment: The event being called is specific to the combobox.  Copying and pasting the combobox does not replicate the code behind the combobox.

Comment: Click on the ComboBox and you should be able to see the name of the ComboBox, (if you are unsure of how to find the name just ask) then in the code replace where it says ComboBox5 with the new ComboBox name, you can have multiple subs, one for each ComboBox on the sheet.

Comment: Hi Both, Thank you for the assistance. Have managed to find another method around through your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Here's three ways to do it depending on what type of combobox you have.

With an ActiveX control:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    CB_ActiveX_Change Me.ComboBox1
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
    CB_ActiveX_Change Me.ComboBox2
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox3_Change()
    CB_ActiveX_Change Me.ComboBox3
End Sub

Public Sub CB_ActiveX_Change(cb As ComboBox)

    With cb.Parent
        'Cells returns a single cell range, no need to wrap in RANGE.
        '(cb.Value = "Courier") will return TRUE/FALSE which can be passed straight to the Hidden property of the control.
        .Cells(cb.TopLeftCell.Row + 1, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = (cb.Value = "Courier")
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Using a form control.  Assign this macro to each control:

```
Public Sub CB_FormControl_Change()
    
    With Sheet1.Shapes(Application.Caller)
        .TopLeftCell.EntireRow.Hidden = (.ControlFormat.List(.ControlFormat.Value) = "Courier")
    End With

End Sub
```

Using a data validation drop-down list:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count = 1 Then
        If HasValidation(Target) Then
            Cells(Target.Row + 1, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = (Target.Value = "Courier")
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Public Function HasValidation(Cell As Range) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
        HasValidation = (Cell.Validation.Type = 3)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```